# Re-directing to dynamic href in PHP script using JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, redirect

I have a drop down user menu that contains child links that I cannot get to redirect properly. I unfortunately did not code the front-end, so I'm just trying to get it to link to dynamic PHP urls. I'm also working within the CodeIgniter framework, by the way. There are two clicks in the user's process (similar to Google's user icon). 1. You click the user image and drop down arrow, 2. You see profile, settings, logout.

With the following script, clicking the drop-down arrow redirects to the first link, profile, without even doing the drop-down animation. Any thoughts?

Here's the PHP file:

```
<div class="user css3"> 
<a href="" class="css3"> <img src="images/user.jpg" alt="user" class="css3" /> </a>
    <div class="child css3">
      <ul class="user_links">
        <li><a href="<?=base_url()?>/profile/view/<?=$userID?>/myfeed">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?=base_url()?>/settings/">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?=base_url()?>/login/logout">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here's the JavaScript for drop-down arrow button:

```
$('div.user').click(function() {
    $('div.user div.child').slideToggle("fast");
    $('div.live div.action div.category div.child, div.live div.action div.sort div.child').slideUp();
    return false;
});
```

Here's the JavaScript that I came up with for the `<ul>` (I'm not much of a JS dev. haha):

```
$('ul.user_links li a').click(function() {
    document.location($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need JavaScript here? I mean, the code you posted is not necessary, the anchors will take the user to their href URL without any js.

Comment: Could you post an online example?

Comment: @MarcB The drop-down arrow is supplied in the CSS via the class.

Comment: @bfavaretto I'll add the JS for the for the drop down button that is working, but apparently dis-allowing the <a> to actually to work on these <li>'

Comment: @MarkLinus I don't have something available at the moment. It's a locked down project for right now. I'll see if I can throw something together though.

Comment: Remove the js for the `<ul>`, and the `return false` from the other block, and it should work.

Comment: @bfavaretto No offense intended, but I both want to hug you and punch you. hahaha. That was so simple, and completely fixed it. I don't spend much time in JS, so I'm not surprised it was something easy, but I've been playing with this for hours before deciding to post on here. Thank you sir!!

Comment: Posted an answer with the explanation, I hope it doesn't make you wanna punch me (or hug me) harder! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I said in the comments:

> Remove the js for the `<ul>`, and then `return false` from the other block, and it should work.

Here is why: when you click an anchor, the event starts propagating upwards through the document structure (the DOM). When it reaches another element wired to catch the `click` event, it runs this element's event handler.

When you click the anchor, the `click` handler on `div.user` runs. The last statement there, `return false`, means "stop the event propagation, and prevent the default behavior". On an anchor, the default behavior would be to follow the link. Your code told the browser not to do it.

Answer (score 0):

try adding an onclick event to the drop down that returns false, thus stopping the default action for links.

```
<a href="" class="css3" onclick="javascript:return false"> <img src="images/user.jpg" alt="user" class="css3" /> </a>
```

Or changing it so it's just a 'span' tag instead of a 'a' tag. You'd have to change the JQuery selector that causes the drop down as well so that it looks for 'span' instead of 'a'

I'm not sure why you need change the default behaviour of the links 3 links though, they would redirect to the href location anyway surely?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this! Yeah, I'm not sure why the JS code isn't allowing them to "just work", haha. I was hoping to just slap the dynamic URLs in there, but it doesn't redirect at all.

Comment: @blackairplane sorry, i had the 'span' and 'a' missing from previous answer cos i put html tags round it! edited it now. It'll prob work if you remove the click handlers. See Abdullahs answer. I'm guessing the drop down arrow being a link is casing problems though so either nullify the 'onclick' event as described above or change it to a 'span' tag

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Actually ended up being @bfavaretto's simple fix above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the root cause, but anyways use:

```
window.location = $(this).attr("href");
```

Instead of

```
document.location($(this).attr("href"));
```